# android.widget.TextView InflateException in Api 10

Tags: java, android, textview, compatibility, android-version

At first I was not supporting lower Android versions. As I had to I converted `minSdkVersion` to `Api 10`. I keep getting the error (below the layout code). I have included `android-support-v4.jar`. As far as I know, `android.widget.textview` is working with `Api10` (I tested it). So what is causing this.

**Error:**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
```

P.S. It is working on Api 16

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.myproject.LoginActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginTip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:text="Log in!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="39sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_email"
        android:text="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="39sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#D1D1D1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logotext"
        android:src="@drawable/logontext_old" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproject/com.myproject.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2206)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.myproject.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:61)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  ... 11 more
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  ... 25 more
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131034118' as integer
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:343)
09-29 16:31:38.723: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  ... 28 more
```

Comment: can you change from `sp` to `dip` and see if it does make any difference?

Comment: Seems to be a program with some id. Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning...  What do you mean program with some id?

Comment: How are you trying to access the `TextView` in your Java code?

Comment: *by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131034118*

Comment: `TextView loginTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginTip);`

Comment: Thing is that I completely removed the textview from the activity but still kept getting the same error

Comment: It works fine for me with Api level 10.. :-s (without your dimens and background)

Comment: What do you mean by dimens? Can you copy snippet?

Comment: Try changing the id of your password edittext

Comment: Well but for all that's worth, and if you didn't change your xml the error is on your password editText. Remember that editText extends from TextView.

Comment: Good point.
Just now I've created another application and copied layout and java code. Works fine. 
One difference is that I am using googple play services for push notifications in real app which I commented in test app. But this should not be reason since it tells me `Textview` inflate exception, right?

Comment: I guess you problem is on the id of the edittext. But since restart/clear your project didn't work than I don't know. Maybe some problem with duplicate ids or something

Comment: @PedroOliveira but in that case it shoud result in error in API 16 too, right?

Comment: That is true. Have you tried removing the edittext too?

Comment: I created another app with exactly the same code and layout and it worked fine win api 10... :/